# Node Mustache: How to get each value of an Array on a separate Radio Button?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mustache

Environment:  Node, Express, Mu2Express, mongoose

What I want to do is get an array from mongoose and have the template render each value as its own radio button.

Can't find an example.

What I currently have:

The route in app.js:

```
app.get('/mutest',function(req, res){
  var data = [1,2,3,4];
  res.render('muTest',{
    'locals': {
      data: data }});
});
```

The template (muTest.mustache)

```
<form name="test" action="muTest" method="post">
    {{#data}}
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value={{data}}>{{data}}<br/>
    {{/data}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The result:

- 1,2,3,4
- 1,2,3,4
- 1,2,3,4
- 1,2,3,4

and, of course, choosing any of the buttons submits the value of "1,2,3,4".

**What I want:**
is for the page to be rendered like this:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4

with a single value (e.g. the string "3") submitted.

TIA for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is that you have to refer to the current item being pointed at:

In the first case, you're using {{data}} as the value (and the text of your radio button) which refers to the data array.

In the second case, you're using {{data[0]}} which will always refer to the first element of the array.

For mustache (super spec compliant) you have to wrap the values (1,2,3,4) into an object:

```
data = [
   {value: 1, label: 1}, 
   {value: 2, label: 2}, 
   ....
];
```

Then:

```
<form name='test' action='muTest' method='post'>
    {{#data}}
        <input type='radio' name='choice' value={{#value}}>{{#label}}</input/><br/>
    {{/data}}
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
</form>
```

---

In mustache.js, the {{.}} operator is like using a 'this' object in javascript (or self in python, etc):

```
<form name='test' action='muTest' method='post'>
    {{#data}}
        <input type='radio' name='choice' value={{.}}>{{.}}</input/><br/>
    {{/data}}
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
</form>
```

And the output is:

```
<form name='test' action='muTest' method='POST'>
    <input type='radio' name='choice' value='1'>1</input><br/>
    <input type='radio' name='choice' value='2'>2</input><br/>
    <input type='radio' name='choice' value='3'>3</input><br/>
    <input type='radio' name='choice' value='4'>4</input><br/>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
</form>
```

Comment: rangerdanger also shared with me the javascript to do this.

data.map(function(d) { return {value: d};})

then in the template use {{value}}